# O_DIRECT not defined on Arch LInux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, gcc

I'm trying to write some low latency disk access code. The issue is that the library I'm using has the following code:

```
#ifdef O_DIRECT
  int flags = O_DIRECT;
#else
  int flags = 0;
#endif
```

and my installation doesn't have `O_DIRECT` defined.
I've confirmed this via this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
#ifdef O_DIRECT
        printf("O_DIRECT");
#else
        printf("Otherwise");
#endif
}
```

Which prints `Otherwise`.

So the question is why is this not defined? And additionally how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macro is actually [defined in](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html#SYNOPSIS) `<fcntl.h>`, not stdio.h.

Second, to access the definition, you need to `#define _GNU_SOURCE` as it is [Linux-specific](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html#CONFORMING_TO). Note that the definition must go before *any* libc header includes, not just before fcntl.h.